# Find a $4$ digit number $n^2$ that is a square of some number $n.$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The rest of the description is like that:
The thousands' digit is equal of the tens' digit and the hundreds' digit is greater by one than the ones' digit.

So the $n^2$ looks like this:

$n^2 = 1000x + 100(y+1) +10x +y$

And after some transformation I was able to show it like this:

$(n-10)(n+10) = 101(10x+y)$

Though, I am stuck here. Not quite sure what I should do next. I was able to find the number by the trial and error method because I know that $n$ must be two digits number:

$n = 91$

$n^2 = 8281$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As $101$ is prime, one of the factors on the left must be $101$ or a multiple of it.  As $n$ has two digits, the only candidate is $n=91$, which gives $n+10=101$ and you are done.